# Detecting change in xml structure stored as clob

Tags: oracle

I have a table that contains an xml document stored as a clob.

```
TabA
----
Name varchar2(30) (PK)
Definition clob
other attributes
```

Note: "Definition" is the clob column that stores the XML.
Typical data volume: 1500 rows.

My requirement is to do some kind of recon and only process those rows on a daily basis that have undergone change to the XML and process those rows that have come in as new.
Identifying rows that came in new and processing only them is easy and can be done with "minus" on the name.
But, is there a good way to identify the XMLs in the existing rows that have undergone change ?

For eg: If an element within an XML has been removed or its attributes changed from the previous day, then I should be able to process that "Name" row.

Example of the typical XML in the table:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataMart asOfDriver="EFFECTIVE_DATE" chainedData="false" classification="" convertUsingFxRate="false" coreEntityIndicator="false" createdAt="2011-12-22T17:41:11.002" createdBy="user1" description="" entitled="false" entitlementDriver="false" hierarchicalFlag="false" innerJoin="false" intent="Intermediate" lastUpdatedAt="2012-07-26T16:11:42.424" lastUpdatedBy="p459807" martType="SPOT" martUsage="Persistent" ownerRole="Meta Model SSC" preAggregatedData="false" referenceDataIndicator="false" retention="" rollupFunction="" staticAggregationOnly="false" status="ACTIVE" tags="">
<name>Name1</name>
<sources>
    <source isDefault="false" name="S1"></source>
</sources>
<rowType-mapping>
    <rowType identifier="0">
    <element alias="E1" name="E1" source="" sourceAlias="" sourceType="system" trackSource="false">
      <description localDescription="false"></description>
          <validationRule type="None"></validationRule>
          <mapping columnName="E1" function="" tableName="TABA"></mapping>
          <Opaque />
    </element>
    More element tags
    ...<element> </element>
    </rowType>
</rowType-mapping>
<parameters>
    <parameter filter="N" name="P1">
      <![CDATA[PM]]>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
</dataMart>
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [trigge](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)r to log changed items to another table. Process what ever was logged in the log table for a particular day.

On how to compare two XMLs refer to [this](http://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/comparing-xml-in-oracle/)

Comment: i am not asking about ways to process it. I am asking about identifying the changed elements within the XML.

Comment: Check out [this](http://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/comparing-xml-in-oracle/) on how to compare XML using PL/SQL

Comment: @user1617637, it would help if you could explain exactly why this answer doesn't help you. On the face of it you could easily have a trigger that captures update / insert statements and just inserts the pk into a different table so that you would know what PKs have changed (obviously not the actual data). What do you need to identify that this doesn't help with?

Comment: Again, As stated earlier, I am not interested in methods to process changes. It can be done in different ways trigger being one of them. But, i wanted to know how changes to an XML structure stored as a clob could be identified. Once I manage to detect that the particular XML has changed, I know I can always get that row using the PK and isolate it for further processing. if you read my comments trace, But, the person had subsequently edited his comment to put out a link to compare 2 xmls (which is what I am looking for) and I am still looking into it.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. But, the DIFF routine seems to have lot of limitations and assumes lot of things. It does not suit my requirement of just identifying if the XML changed or not from its previous incarnation.I am not interested in knowing what changed within so long as I can identify if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

It would only be possible if you keep a record of your previous (old) xml in a log or temp table before updating the New XML.

By the looks of the question, it seems that you not only want to compare the XML with its previous version but also find out "what has changed?".

A good way to compare and find what has changed is to do a `diff` between the old and new XML. [Here](http://pastebin.com/eLHhPzPn) is a package which does a diff on `CLOB`. See if you can use it to fit your needs.

Or

You can convert the `CLOB` to `Varchar` using `dbms_lob.substr( clob_column, for_how_many_bytes, from_which_byte );` and then do something like below to do a `diff` on the two new `VARCHAR`s-

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TRANSLATE('abcdef','abc',RPAD(' ',LENGTH('abcdef'))))) val
  FROM dual;

VAL
----------
def
```

Comment: I am not interested in what has changed within the XML so long as I can identify if it has changed from its previous version. If it has changed, then I can use the PK of the XML to re-process that row. But, I will look into your DIFF routine to see if it fits. Thanks.

Comment: I meant PK of the row that contains the XML column, not the PK of the XML !

Comment: To find if the XML has changed you can see if there was a previous version of the XML from the log table (which, as I mentioned you would populate using a trigger).